# Will translation units built with different FUSION_MAX_VECTOR_SIZE (and similar) be linkable with each other?

Tags: c++, gcc, boost-mpl, boost-fusion

I work on a large computational project that heavily use `boost::mpl` and `boost:fusion` on C++11.

Sometimes, in order to get some translation units to compile, I have to define the following BOOST macros:

```
FUSION_MAX_VECTOR_SIZE=40
FUSION_MAX_MAP_SIZE=40
BOOST_FUSION_DONT_USE_PREPROCESSED_FILES
BOOST_FUSION_INVOKE_MAX_ARITY=40
BOOST_RESULT_OF_NUM_ARGS=40
BOOST_MPL_LIMIT_VECTOR_SIZE=40
BOOST_MPL_CFG_NO_PREPROCESSED_HEADERS=1
```

And yes, these definitions add significantly to the compile time. That's why I consider setting those variables on per-translation-unit basis.

Now the question arises, will translation units built with different settings of those variables be linkable with each other?

Someone in my organization suggests that, it would lead to the undefined behavior. My intuition tells me otherwise - after all, `boost::mpl` and `boost::fusion` are header-only, so anything that links, should be just a mangled plain C function, and if there are any incompatibilities, those will be necessary caught during the linking phase. But I may be wrong.

Comment: Not familiar with boost fusion, but header only doesn't mean nothing bad ever happens. Consider `inline int foo() { return X; }`, with `X` defined differently for each TU.

Comment: Does `FUSION_MAX_VECTOR_SIZE` even matter in C++11 mode?